# Android gcm - trouble adding it to my project

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to add gcm to my project and I am facing many issues.
After I managed to sgn up and download the configuration files, I put the json file in the app folder, and this is what I have in my gradle father file:

`dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'`

and this is what I have on my gradle app file:

`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

but when I try to run it, it says:

`Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
No matching client found for package name 'com.example.a.feedapp'`

what can I do?

Answer (score 1):

i would recommend you start with FCM it's the new version of GCM and pretty easy integrating it in your app

> [Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) is the new version of GCM. It inherits
>   the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus new features! See
>   the [FAQ](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#messaging-difference) to learn more. If you are integrating messaging in a new app,
>   start with FCM. GCM users are strongly recommended to upgrade to FCM,
>   in order to benefit from new FCM features today and in the future.

Comment: when I try to download the configuration file, it asks me for my app package name, but my app isn't on the store yet, it's just on my computer, so what should I give them...?

Comment: no problem if the app isn't in store just give him the package name as it is in your app

Comment: again, facing troubles with installing... I downliaded the configuration file, put it on the app folder, added what what I needed in the gradle and get those errors: `Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-messaging/9.0.0/firebase-messaging-9.0.0.pom....` any ideas?

Comment: have you added this line classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' to app build.gradle (not module ) and this compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0' to your module gradle and at the bottom of it this line apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: Looks like you need to update your sdk via SDK manager in Android Studio. Make sure you have Google Play services Rev. 30 installed.